# Instances and Object Info Nodes - Geometry Nodes Problem

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm currently a beginner using Blender 3D, and I'm following a tutorial to get some experience with the software. I have a problem when doing Geometry Nodes on Blender. When I insert the `Object Info` node onto the `Instance on Points` node, the multiplied objects won't appear on the targeted mesh. I tried doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and *Apply Scale*, but nothing seemed to work. When I do it on the Icing layer, it just scales the mesh to an unreasonable amount. Is there any way I fix this problem?

###### Screenshots:

This is the expectation I'm trying to follow, a.k.a, the tutorial:
[image: Belnder Donut Tutorial (Expectation)]

And this is what I got:
[image: Reality]

I'm currently using Blender 3.4.0, with Windows 10 Version 22H2. I hope these screenshots help!

###### With Regards...

Comment: Your `Distribute Points on Faces` node is not linked to anything so it can't distribute any points. Link your `Group Input` *Geometry* into its *Mesh* socket.

Comment: Okay, that worked, but I ran into another problem. I realized the scale was applied improperly from the target object. It took me time to realize that the bigger I scale the target object, the more properly the Instance scales by hitting Ctrl + A every time a scale is made. Is there a solution to this? Here's a screenshot of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVB4RV9n3uhLkojRg1LuyhghQiJfLhDC/view?usp=share_link 

With Regards,

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you rephrase your question? What is the "target" object, the donut or the seed you're distributing? What are their scales?

Comment: Hi, I will start a new thread further explaining this problem. Thank you for your time and effort in helping me solve the last issue I dealt with!

Comment: Here's the link in regards to the second question in more detail: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287928/blender-donut-tutorial-part-9-and-10-improper-scale-geometry-nodes-in-blen